# ASP.NET radio button in repeater show old value

Tags: asp.net

I was put into my repeater binding radiobutton but when user click on radio more than once, then it shows incorrect value.

This is how it looks:

```
Show 7 but should 11
```

https://d3higte790sj35.cloudfront.net/images/kd/gm/6b5ad5669c95d5875c31d8f6d8a2c751.png

Here is the code

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        RadioButton control = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1");

        if (control.Checked)
        {
           Label3.Text = control.Text;
        }

        ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
    }

    (sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;
}


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Text='<%# Eval("ProductCode") %>' runat ="server"  GroupName="r1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" ClientIDMode="AutoID" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Size="14"  />
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Icon") %>' CssClass="ter-choce-icon" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <br />   
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Get One" CssClass="Get" Visible="False" CommandName="t1" />
            </FooterTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate><br /></SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Since the radiobutton is inside the repeater I think you should do: Repeater1.DataBind() right after (sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;

Comment: It works but in this case the radio is unchecked and this can confuse the user in what he chooses

Comment: What if you bind before the checked is set to true, still same?

Comment: Yes stil is. With Bind i get corect value but radio is unchecked.

Comment: Try UpdatePanel1.Update() after the databind.

Comment: With UpdatePanel1.Update(); i can checked every radio button (i want only one) but i don't get value from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You process `RadioButton` event so the button clicked is immediately available as `sender`. The only thing you need to uncheck all other radiobuttons. `GroupName` doesn't work in a `Repeater`. Something like this.

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label3.Text = (sender as RadioButton).Text;
    var thisItem = (sender as RadioButton).NamingContainer;
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item != thisItem)
        {
            (item.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton).Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        RadioButton control = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1");

        if (control.Checked)
        {
           Label3.Text = control.Text;
        }

        ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
    }

    (sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;
}
```

In this code why do you need these lines

```
 ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
  (sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;
```

As per me the radiobutton should change its checked status without your code.
Remove these lines and run again